# ValueError at /new Cannot assign "'Home'": "Listing.category" must be a "Category" instance

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to create a new listing but I get this error:

```
(ValueError at /new
Cannot assign "'Work'": "Listing.category" must be a "Category" instance.)
```

Models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64, default="")
    starting_bid = models.CharField(max_length=64, default="$")
    description = models.TextField(default="")
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
def new_listing(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        title = request.POST["title"]
        starting_bid = request.POST["starting_bid"]
        image_url = request.POST["image_url"]
        category = request.POST["category"]
        description = request.POST["description"]


        ins = Listing(title=title, starting_bid=starting_bid, image_url=image_url, category=category, description=description)
        ins.save()
    categories = Category.objects.filter()

    return render(request, "auctions/new_listing.html", { "categories": categories })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set a value to the `ForeignKey` you need an object.

> (ValueError at /new Cannot assign "'Work'": "Listing.category" must be
> a "Category" instance.)

You can use instead an attribute with `_id` at the end or use the Category object.

```
category_id=category
# Get category object
Category.objects.get(name=category)
```

views.py:

```
def new_listing(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        query = request.POST
        title = query.get("title")
        starting_bid = query.get("starting_bid")
        image_url = query.get("image_url")
        category = query.get("category")
        description = query.get("description")

        category_obj = Category.objects.get(name=category)
        """
        ins = Listing(
            title=title, starting_bid=starting_bid, 
            image_url=image_url, category_id=category, 
            description=description
        )
        """
        # OR
        ins = Listing(
            title=title, starting_bid=starting_bid, 
            image_url=image_url, category=category_obj, 
            description=description
        )
        ins.save()
    categories = Category.objects.all()

    return render(request, "auctions/new_listing.html", { "categories": categories })
```

---

> Behind the scenes, Django appends **"_id"** to the field name to
> create its database column name, see [**Django ForeignKey**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#database-representation)

---

**Also I recommend you to [Working with forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/).**

Comment: Thank you. but when changed it to category_id, I got this error- ValueError at /new
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Laptops'

Comment: @NurudeenAhmed, 'Laptops' is it a name of the category?

Comment: Then use: `Category.objects.get(name=category)`

Comment: @NurudeenAhmed, and make the field name unique=True to prevent duplicate names.

Comment: it worked when i used Category.objects.get(category=category). THANK YOU SO MUCH! i've been trying since